# JS order array of objects by object property (dollars)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am having a heck of a time figuring this one out.
I have an array of objects in my vuejs app like so:

```
var food= [{'name':'apples','price':'222.30'},{'name':'bananas','price':'99.30'},{'name':'oranges','price':'199.30'}];
```

When I try to sort by price, I am trying both

```
return food.sort((a, b) => (a.price> b.price) ? 1 : -1);
AND
return _.orderBy(food, 'price')
```

However it seems this interprets the price $99.30 as higher than $222.30 - I am assuming because 9 is higher than 2?

Any help would be appreciated! I am also wondering if there is a way to order largest to smallest and vice versa.

Comment: your prices are string.  need to make them numeric values

Comment: Do the prices have to be in single quotes. Could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert the price to a number and use in your sort callback

```
return food.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.price) -  parseFloat(b.price));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code, is the values are strings.

A simple fix:

```
return food.sort((a, b) => (parseFloat(a.price) > parseFloat(b.price)) ? 1 : -1);
```

Comment: Quote: *"That's... not how sort() works  it expects 0, 1, or -1"* And when it is equal?

Answer (score 0):

The prices are stored as `string`s; this makes it hard. It will compare each price as strings, one character at a time, left to right.

Consider converting to `float`s and simplifying the code:

```
return food.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Number

```js
var food= [{'name':'apples','price':'222.30'},{'name':'bananas','price':'99.30'},{'name':'oranges','price':'199.30'}];


food.sort((a, b) => (Number(a.price) > Number(b.price)) ? 1 : -1);

console.log(food);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your sort is not working as aspected because you comparing price as string**

```
var food= [{'name':'apples','price':'222.30'},{'name':'bananas','price':'99.30'},{'name':'oranges','price':'199.30'}];

 function compare( a, b ) {
  if ( parseFloat(a.price) < parseFloat(b.price) ){
    return -1;
  }
  if ( parseFloat(a.price) > parseFloat(b.price) ){
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

food.sort( compare );

or


food.sort((a, b) => (parseFloat(a.price) > parseFloat(b.price)) ? 1 : -1);
```