# Sort by multiple condition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two columns of value. If the first column any value becomes 0 then sort by another column value.

**Probable input**

```
Django      Rect
10          20
20          11
1           100
100         1
0           1
0           100
0           9
0           0
0           0
```

**Expected out**

```
Django      Rect
100         1
20          11
10          20
1           100
0           100
0           9
0           1
0           0
0           0
```

I would expect descending order sort. I can sort for any of one column but I need to sort at a time two-column according to the given condition.
I have tried so far

```
all_data.sort(function(a,b){
      return a.Django- b.Django;
    }
);
```

Comment: you should search javascript not react, reference [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Comment: Is th output of second column sorted ? All I can see that the data is arranged in random manner.

Comment: @AL-zami I asked if Django is 0 then react will sort by desc order. Before that Django will sort by desc order

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66959021/7924858

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue looks like this: *"The ordinal property you want to sort by"*.

To be more precise, when you should sort `Django` and `Rect`.

```
const all_data = [{Django:10,Rect:20},{Django:20,Rect:11},{Django:1,Rect:100},{Django:100,Rect:1},{Django:0,Rect:1},{Django:0,Rect:100},{Django:0,Rect:9},{Django:0,Rect:0},{Django:0,Rect:0}];

all_data.sort((a, b) => b.Django - a.Django || b.Rect - a.Rect);
console.log(all_data);
```

### Explain:

***Firstly***, sort desc by `Django`. ***Secondly,*** if `Django` is the same, then will sort desc by `Rect`

Answer (score -1):

You say that you only want to sort by `Rect` when `Django` is 0. However, it seems to me that it's better to sort by `Rect` in all cases where `a.Django === b.Django`.

You can check for equality in your compare function.

```
all_data.sort(function(a,b) {
        if (a.Django === b.Django) {
            return a.Rect - b.Rect;
        }
        return a.Django- b.Django;
    }
);
```

Comment: Can be shortened to `all_data.sort((a, b) => b.Django - a.Django || b.Rect - a.Rect);`